# Código de conduta sem tradução

Tags: bug, status-revisão, tradução

Reparei recentemente que nosso [código de conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct) possui vários trechos sem tradução. Tá uma mistura de inglês com português.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Infelizmente este não é o primeiro problema de tradução neste site, mas me recuso a querer um posicionamento mais definitivo de quem coloca esse conteúdo no nosso site.

Comment: Parece que é um daqueles problemas que nunca irão resolver. [Já reclamei disso ano passado](/a/8874/112052), e claro, se pesquisar aqui no Meta vai achar várias outras reclamações similares, e bem mais antigas. E nunca foi feito nada que melhorasse esse processo. Quer dizer, até mudaram algumas coisas, mas o problema principal permanece: quase sempre quando atualizam o site, alguma coisa volta a ficar em inglês. É mais uma das coisas que cansei de ficar reclamando, porque no fundo já me conformei que é algo que não será resolvido

Comment: @hkotsubo sabemos que a SE tem feito um péssimo trabalho em quase tudo o que faz, principalmente sobre traduções, mas mesmo assim me sinto no dever de deixar mais um alerta dentre as dezenas que já temos aqui.